# how to position divs within another div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I want to position divs within another div.

Here's the relevant snippet of css ([full example on cssdesk](http://cssdesk.com/uAQgD)):

```
        .textblock-container {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        div.textblock {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            line-height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;             
            background: rgb(0, 150, 0); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't
                                support rgba */
            background: rgba(0, 150, 0, .5);
        }
```

and the relevant snippet of html:

```
    <div id='blockdiv1' class='textblock-container'>
        <div id='blockdiv2' class='textblock'><span>foo (NW)</span></div>
        <div id='blockdiv3' class='textblock'><span>bar (NE)</span></div>
        <div id='blockdiv4' class='textblock'><span>baz (SW)</span></div>
        <div id='blockdiv5' class='textblock'><span>quux (SE)</span></div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that the foo/bar/baz/quux blocks are positioned relative to the browser window, not to their parent element.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the parent `.textblock-container` div.

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their nearest positioned parent (e.g. the nearest parent element with a position of `absolute` or `relative`), so if they have no explicitly positioned parents (default position is `static`) they will be relative to the window.

Comment: added a brief explanation :)

Comment: also when it comes to offset values (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` properties), an absolutely positioned element will be offset relative to the top left of its closest positioned parent, while a relatively positioned element is offset relative to its original position in the page flow (just so you understand the purpose of `position: relative` outside of being an 'anchor' position for absolutely positioned descendants) @JasonS

Answer (score 8):

Unless you add `position: relative;` to the parent controller the div will be positioned absolute of the window

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
.textblock-container {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
border: 1px solid red;
position: relative;
}

div.textblock {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;             
background: rgb(0, 150, 0);
background: rgba(0, 150, 0, .5);
}
```

In fact, you just have to add the `position: relative` propertie for the parent div.