# tooltip gets cut off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a tool-tip that should be appear front of "click me" button. I used offset().top for that. But having below mentioned issue.

1) When i am clicking on bottom buttons tool-tip gets inside the page.
2) I don't want to remove the overflow:hidden from parent div.
3) I want tool-tip should not go inside the container, instead i want tool-tip should move upward before touching the bottom of the container.

Please let me know the work around.

```
$(".main").on("click", "button", function(){
  var top = $(this).offset().top;
  $(".pop").show(".pop");
  $(".pop").css("top", top)

})

$(".pop").click(function(){
  $(this).css("display", "none")
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main">  
  <table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">Text</td>
    <td width="50%"><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div class="pop">
        <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
      </div>
 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**When i click the bottom button, tool-tip should Aligned to the bottom of the page**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyZdqO

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Is it "will someone please write code for my specification"?

Comment: Where should the `.pop` appear when you click the bottom button? Aligned to the bottom of the page? Aligned to the top edge of the button? There are so many possible answers here.

Comment: want to make it Aligned to the bottom of the page

Comment: @amphetamachine ..want to make it Aligned to the bottom of the page

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the html to this question too. You can even make a fully functional snippet here via the button above the edit field.

Comment: @Sumurai8 . I have already added http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyZdqO sample link to check the HTML and js.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.But if your tooltip is going below,then you can try  z-index in your css.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that the .pop does not open past the border of .main you need to make .pop relatively positioned 
Also review: [How to position divs within another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620355/how-to-position-divs-within-another-div)